# return JQM slider to it's "fresh" state programmatically

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider

Whe creating a new JQM slider with

```
<input type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1" min="0" max="10" />
```

The slider will be originally displayed with no value in the text box.
After selecting any value there is always a number in the text box.

What is the correct way to programmatically return the slider to the initial "no value" state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling

```
$("#slider1").val(0).slider("refresh");
```

will return the slider to the start position. But will still show `0` in the textbox.
Then

```
$("#slider1").val('');
```

is enough to reset the slider textbox.

See live example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtgdd/).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#slider1").slider("value", $("#slider1").slider("option", "min") );
```

or

```
$("#slider1").val(0).slider("refresh");
```